# How to check if cell contains wildcard asterisk (*) character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Consider the following two formulas:**

```
=IF(SEARCH("*", A1), "true", "false")

=IF(SEARCH(CHAR(42), A1), "true", "false")
```

I am using this to try and detect if a cell contains a **`*`** character, but this returns "true" for all cells. I can only assume that Excel sees **`*`** as a wildcard maybe.

How do you detect the existence of a **`*`** in Excel?

Comment: I think you may be able to use the tilde "~" character to escape the star in a search.

Comment: Zack's answer is correct

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to this reference of [microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214138) you should be able to use `~`

> Microsoft Excel uses the tilde (~) as a marker to indicate that the
>   next character is a literal. When you use the Find and Replace dialog
>   box to find or replace a character such as a tilde (~), an asterisk
>   (*), or a question mark (?), you must add a tilde (~) before the
>   character in the Find what box.

So change `=IF(SEARCH("*", A1), "true", "false")` to  `=IF(SEARCH("~*", A1), "true", "false")` and it should work.

Comment: Not to pick nits but since case sensitivity has no bearing on the outcome, `FIND` may be a marginally more efficient function to use for this. e.g. `=ISNUMBER(FIND("~*", A1))`. `#VALUE!` on no match is not `FALSE`.